# JavaScript IIFE Evaluation is undefined

Tags: javascript, iife, iif-function

Hello I‘m a beginner at JavaScript and I‘m trying to figure out how IIFE work, and I still have some trouble. In the lecture I stumbled upon this example code, and the evaluation of the code below gives the result „undefined“ whereas calling the function with „add()“ returns 1 and I really don’t understand why, since function is an IIFE.

```
var add = (function() {
       var counter = 0;

       return function() {
            counter += 1;
            return counter 
       }
})();
//Output: undefined
```

Comment: `undefined` is just what you see in the console after an assignment, as here. Your code looks fine: if you keep invoking `add()` afterwards you should see the output increase by 1 each time.

Comment: Okay, yeah but makes sense I was just confused because it’s a function expression this time, but yes it is still a declaration. But how does this work, which of the counter variable do I actually modify? Always the one in the return statement right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You IIFE is a [factory function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-factory-functions/). In this case it returns a function, so that works. You can assign the result to a variable and subsequently run the resulting function. The `counter` variable is '[closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)', it will be manipulated (and returned) via the returned function, but it will not be accessible to the 'outside world'.

```js
// assign the result to a variable
const add = (function() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
})();

// add is a function: execute it a few times
add();
add();
console.log(add()); // => 3
```

Comment: Ah good to know, I never heard of that term factory function before! True functions in JS are (first-class) objects. So you mean the Variable counter in the first line „let counter = 0“ will be manipulated by the function in the return statement?

Comment: What gets returned (from the IIFE) and assigned to `add` is ... the function, ready to invoke subsequently - period ;) Invoking the resulting function itself (so `add`) returns the value of `counter`, after it is incremented with 1.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your IIFE. You are only seeing the result of the `var` statement. Examples:

```js
var x = function() {};
//=> undefined
var x = 42;
//=> undefined
var x = true;
//=> undefined
```

An assignment expression will evaluate to the value on the right:

```js
y = 10;
//=> 10
```

But the `var` statement itself returns nothing:

```js
var y = 10;
//=> undefined
```

Relevant part of the spec:

> VariableDeclaration : BindingPattern Initializer
>
> 1. Let rhs be the result of evaluating Initializer.
> 2. Let rval be ? GetValue(rhs).
> 3. Return the result of performing BindingInitialization for BindingPattern passing rval and undefined as arguments.

See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement

Answer (score -1):

For IIFE you need to wrap your anonymous function in "( )" and then invoke it with "();"
It does not allow declaration. try removing declaration.

```
(function() {
   var counter = 0;

   return function() {
        counter += 1;
        return counter 
   }
})();
```

For more info refer this.
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife

Comment: The „var add =” isn’t by accident, I got this example from our lecture about Closures in JS :D But thanks for the reference, I will have a look.